# How to apply update delete query in installation class in Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfinstallation

I am working on application in which I use one to one push notification using Parse.

I Use installation  class for that,but I am not able to apply update or delete query in installation class

[image].

In the above picture there is multiple entry of same USERID.

I want to check if USERID is already in installation class just update that column.

below is my code where I get the detail of installation class and  use query with USERID.

```
  PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

        NSLog(@"%@",installation);

        PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query ];

        [query whereKey:@"USERID" equalTo:getUserId];
```

but don't know which code I have to use for update query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried and the logged results / errors

Comment: @Wain I have updated the question

Comment: Did you try updating the instance returned and saving it. You may need to do it in cloud code...

Comment: @Wain Can you please share some code?

Comment: Your code givase me following error .Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.

Comment: What do you mean by "just update that column" and "which code I have to use for update query"?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,check whether user is present or not:-**

```
 BOOL isFound=FALSE;
PFQuery *query = [PFInstallation query ];
[query whereKey:@"USERID" equalTo:getUserId]; 
NSError *error=nil;
 NSArray *arrayTest=[query findObjects:&error];
 if(!error)
       {
            if([arrayTest count]>0)
            {
               isFound=TRUE;
            }
        }
```

**Secondly,update the installation object if user found:-**

```
if(isFound)
{
     PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [installation setObject:@"whatever you want to set" forKey:@"ColumnName"];
        [installation saveInBackground]; 
}
```

Comment: Your code givase me following error .Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.

Comment: This error comes when  you are using the Client Key because query to  the Installation class aren't allowed . That's basic!

Comment: Yess !!Exactly ..I just want to kno is there anyother way to modify the installation class.

Comment: This Cloud Function will use the master key to gain permission to query the installation table. Call it from iOS by using PFCloud.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to update `profileName` in parse

```
  let query = PFQuery(className:"User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(myOutput as! String) {
        (currUser: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let currUser = currUser {
              currUser["profileName"] = profilename
             currUser.saveInBackground()
       }

    }
```